# Event Label and Category in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am having trouble implementing event tracking in Google Analytics.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<a id="x" class="herolink" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'banner_click', 'banner', 'events');" href="https://example.com"> <img id="y" src="http://example.com/y.jpg" />
```

Is the syntax correct?  I am not seeing any results when I filter by event label and category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your Real-Time reports, as you won't be able to see data in standard reports until the data is processed, which can take up to 24 hours. The syntax looks correct. Also check with Google Analytics debugger tool (Chrome plugin) to see the hit. If you can see the event in RT, then you should be fine and only need to wait for the data to be processed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the debugger tool, didn't realize that existed.  It showed an "Uncaught Reference Error: ga is not defined".  It looks like the client is not using Universal Analytics

Comment: Ah, good to know, so they are using classic GA? In which case the syntax would need to be changed.